# jQuery: how to return data from a plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, flash

i would like to write my own first plugin.
so far everything works. but how can i make a variable return?
I tried it with a callback function but that did not really work out.

The final objective is to return a variable from a swf.

I hope it is clear what I want and anyone can help.

cheers.

Here is my code (example):

```
    jQuery.crossXML = function( options, callback ) {
    // set default vars
    var defaults = {
        'xmlPath'       : false,
        'method'        : 'init'
    }

    // extend defaults with custom options
    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    //init swf
    if(opts.method == 'init'){
        var flashvars = {
            //currently not required
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            allowScriptAccess:'always'
        };
        var attributes = {
            id: "mySWF",
            name: "mySWF"
        };

        var swfHeight,swfWidth;

        if(opts.debug){
            swfHeight   = "550";
            swfWidth    = "400";
        }else{
            swfHeight   = "1";
            swfWidth    = "1";
        }

        swfobject.embedSWF ( opts.swf, opts.swfContainer, swfHeight, swfWidth, "9", "js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes );
        swfobject.addLoadEvent(loadEventHandler);

     }

     //callback to get data from swf
     function callSWF(var) {
        var flash = getMovie('mySWF');
        flash.callSWF(var);
     }

     if(opts.method == 'call')
        callSWF(opts.myVAR);
}

//executed by flash to get data
function getDataFromSWF(swfDATA) {
    alert(swfDATA);/*#################### this, I would like to have as a return #########*/
}

//get flash-object for calback
function getMovie(movieName) {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
}
```

Comment: That isn't actually a plugin.

Comment: yeah there is no jq plugin here!

Answer (score 0):

Well, my approach would be to attach data to the specific element(in this case - wherever your swf is contained)

```
var elem = $("#SQFdiv").eq(0);
jQuery.data(elem, "swfDATAField1", { myVal: swfDATA });
```

EDIT:

```
$(elem).data("swfDATAField1", myObjData); //preferred method
```

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the approach. but apparently I've not written a real plugin. I will revise it all and maybe it will work then also with the CallBack

Comment: @SLaks: puhtato - pohtato   :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use callbacks within the options of your plugin, for example:

```
$(elem).myPlugin({
    "onStateChange": function(obj) {
        if (obj.foo == "bar") {
            // Do something
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your plugin use:

```
settings.onStateChange.call(this, options);
```